# Faraday ssl3 cipher

Tags: ruby, curl, faraday

I have a working connection with curl that basically requires I specify -ssl3 as the cipher suite to use as tls1 or any other ciphers causes the server to fail the hello handshake.  The curl command that works:

```
curl https://10.10.10.10/soap/rpc -k -v -ssl3 --cert /etc/ssl/mwlang.crt --key /etc/ssl/mwlang.key
```

I did determine with curl that the presence of other cipher suites cause the handshake to fail, but I'm not sure how to specify the ssl3 cipher with Faraday...my attempt so far:

```
SSL_OPTS = {:verify => false,
  :ca_path => "/usr/lib/ssl/certs",
  :client_cert  => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("/etc/ssl/mwlang.crt")),
  :client_key   => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("/etc/ssl/mwlang.key")),
}

Faraday.new(:url => 'https://10.10.10.10', :ssl => SSL_OPTS) do |faraday|
  faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to limit the cipher suite does depend on the adapter used for Faraday.  For the default adapter, the "version" key should be set to :SSLv3

```
SSL_OPTS = {:verify => false,
  :ca_path => "/usr/lib/ssl/certs",
  :client_cert  => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("/etc/ssl/mwlang.crt")),
  :client_key   => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("/etc/ssl/mwlang.key")),
  :version => :SSLv3
}

Faraday.new(:url => 'https://10.10.10.10', :ssl => SSL_OPTS) do |faraday|
  faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
end
```

As others have pointed out to me, SSLv3 is subjected to the POODLE vulnerability.  Please be aware of this if you're using only SSLv3 ciphers:  https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-290A